# I can't build the app when following Ember.js 2.4 "Getting Started" guide

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to learn [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) and so I started to read some installation guides with npm. Then I went to try a small [Getting Started](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/getting-started/quick-start/) tutorial guide they have on their website. I followed each step without to much exploration just to see if it worked well.

Everything went fine, the app was loading and acting as expected on localhost:4200 server and it was pretty nice to develop actually. The problem was on the final step, where you have to build the app with your command line using `ember build --env production` and the `dist/` folder will have your final code. The command line trown some errors and when I went to the `index.html` file on `dist/` folder, the page was blank in Chrome.

This happened in MacOS and Windows 10 to.
I'm using ember-cli version `2.4.3`, node version `4.4.3` and npm version `3.8.9` on a Windows 10 machine x64 architecture.

The error trown by the command line was:

```
Cleanup error.
ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\root\tut\tmp\template_compiler-output_path-NGSFwxV3.tmp\modules\ember-cli-app-version'
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\root\tut\tmp\template_compiler-output_path-NGSFwxV3.tmp\modules\ember-cli-app-version'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:758:18)
    at rmkidsSync (C:\root\tut\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:247:11)
    at rmdirSync (C:\root\tut\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:237:7)
    at fixWinEPERMSync (C:\root\tut\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:150:5)
    at rimrafSync (C:\root\tut\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:216:26)
    at C:\root\tut\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:245:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at rmkidsSync (C:\root\tut\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:244:26)
    at rmdirSync (C:\root\tut\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:237:7)
Built project successfully. Stored in "dist/".
File sizes:
 - tut-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css: 0 B
 - tut-faee034545d48621fa86656f6c15f508.js: 9.15 KB (1.99 KB gzipped)
 - vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css: 0 B
 - vendor-eeea1e3023f3e98422c781bcc7b2588e.js: 689.89 KB (180.23 KB gzipped)
```

I don't know if this affects in anything but I've runned the `ember build` command while the ember server was still rilling.

I wanted to understand if I'm doing something wrong, or if this ember tutorial is outdated, of if anyone has experienced this same problem and how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this issue on github:
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3861

Turns out I didn't have production configured base URL and other stuff I should have.

Comment: +1, had this same issue where it was specific to build (`ember s` works). Realized I was missing baseURL in my environment.js config file.

Answer (score 3):

Just a suggestion.  I wouldn't run `ember b` or `ember build` while the server is running within another console window.

Both `ember build` end `ember serve` run the broccoli build pipeline, wich depends on temporary files in the `tmp` dir. If you start it twice this can lead to problems. Stop your server for the build.

Comment: Well, this makes sense. But unfortunately it wasn't that